# Fix windows magnifier (accessibility tool) for Android Studio?

Tags: windows, android-studio, accessibility

I have a weird problem with Android Studio. I started a empty project and when I started to write code the windows magnifier not works properly.

The function "focus the text entry" is not working when I use Android Studio. I am not sure if this is a problem of my PC or Android Studio. When I code in Visual Studio and Eclipse the Windows magnifier tool I don't have this problem. Here is a [video of the problem](https://youtube.com/watch?v=oZtiV-wgmEU&feature=youtu.be); as you can see the text entry focus does not work only in Android Studio.

Does someone know how to fix that? I don't have good eyes that's why I need the magnifier and the "focus the text entry" function.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the magnifier not working properly? Does it come up but doesn't work, does it not show, etc? I take it this is the Windows one rather than anything built into Android Studio?

Comment: @halfer 

here is a video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZtiV-wgmEU&feature=youtu.be

as you can see the text entry focus not works only in android studio

Comment: I've not seen the video but I don't use AS anyway - my questions are to help other helpers. At this stage, I wonder since this is a rather niche problem it is worth reporting this to the Android Studio bug tracker?